# Running Splash server and Scrapy spiders on the same Ec2 Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, scrapy, splash-screen

I'm deploying a web scraping application composed of [Scrapy](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) spiders that scrape content from websites as well as screenshot webpages with the [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) javascript rendering service. I want to deploy the whole application to a single Ec2 instance. But for the application to work I must run a splash server from a docker image at the same time I'm running my spiders. How can I run multiple processes on an Ec2 instance? Any advice on best practices would be most appreciated.

Comment: This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41221897/running-multiple-ecs-tasks-based-on-same-task-definitions-in-one-host-using-dif) suggests using AWS Elastic Container Service (ECS) as a solution for running multiple tasks on the same Ec2 instance. Any tips on applying this solution in my case? In addition it is crucial that my scrapy spiders be able to communicate with the splash server. Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Total noob question. I found the best way to run a Splash server and Scrapy spiders on an Ec2 instance after configuration is via a bash script scheduled to run with a cronjob. Here is the bash script I came up with:

```
#!bin/bash
# Change to proper directory to run Scrapy spiders.
cd /home/ec2-user/project_spider/project_spider

# Activate my virtual environment.
source /home/ec2-user/venv/python36/bin/activate # activate my virtual environment

# Create a shell variable to store date at runtime 
LOGDATE=$(date +%Y%m%dT%H%M%S);

# Spin up splash instance from docker image.
sudo docker run -d -p 8050:8050 -p 5023:5023 scrapinghub/splash --max-timeout 3600

# Scrape first site and store dated log file in logs directory.
scrapy crawl anhui --logfile /home/ec2-user/project_spider/project_spider/logs/anhui_spider/anhui_spider_$LOGDATE.log

...

# Spin down splash instance via docker image.
sudo docker rm $(sudo docker stop $(sudo docker ps -a -q --filter ancestor=scrapinghub/splash --format="{{.ID}}"))

# Exit virtual environment.
deactivate

# Send an email to confirm cronjob was successful.
#   Note that sending email from Ec2 is difficult and you can not use 'MAILTO' 
#   in your cronjob without setting up something like postfix or sendmail. 
#   Using Mailgun is an easy way around that. 

curl -s --user 'api:<YOURAPIHERE>' \
    https://api.mailgun.net/v3/<YOURDOMAINHERE>/messages \
        -F from='<YOURDOMAINADDRESS>' \
        -F to=<RECIPIENT> \
        -F subject='Cronjob Run Successfully' \
        -F text='Cronjob completed.'
```